# Modifying a list of production goals based on constraints SAS

Tags: sas

I have a list of production goals.  Here are the data.

> data goals;
>
> input product $ w1 w2 w3 w4 w5;
>
> cards;
>
> A 800 400 200 400 100
>
> B 300 400 200 100 100
>
> C 50 25 25 25 25
>
> ;
>
> run;

Now, what I need to do is redistribute the goal based on if production is stopped for some reason.  For example, if the plant is closed on week 1 then I am unable to produce 800 As, 300 Bs, and 50 Cs.  Now I cannot make up all of that lost productivity in week 2, only 50% of it.  o, since I needed 800 As in week1, I will make 400 of those As in week2 (along with what I already had scheduled in week2) and do the same for week3. So I want my new goals to be.

> product w1 w2  w3  w4  w5
>
> A       0  800 600 400 100
>
> B       0  550 350 100 100
>
> C       0  50  50  25  25

So I'm redistributing the goal over the next two weeks, making up 50% of week1 goals each week.

I have experimented with different ways to do this, but unable to make any progress of the syntax.

This is SAS by the way.  I am open to different ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question that's more interesting revolves around how you communicate the W1 values and the change to the program.  The problem of converting ds1 to ds2 is trivial, and how you solve it is connected to the larger question.

One good way to do this is with a macro with parameters appropriate to your needs.  One example:

```
%macro fix_goals(week=,newweek=,percent=50,max=constant(big)); *max set arbitrarily high if not used;
adjusted = min(&newweek.+(&week.*&percent.),&max.); *assumes MAX is the maximum it could accomplish in a week including both the old target and the new target;
&week.=&week.-(adjusted-&newweek.); *how much was added;
&newweek.=adjusted;
%mend fix_goals;
```

Then:

```
data want;
set have;
%fix_goals(week=w1,newweek=w2,percent=50);
%fix_goals(week=w1,newweek=w3,percent=100); *the rest;
run;
```

You could do this a number of similar ways depending on the criteria and how you want to communicate the change to the program.  If you always give it to the next 2 weeks exactly 50/50, the above is slightly more complicated than needed ( but accomplishes it as written).

Comment: Joe--I believe this is exactly what I need.  I am getting an error code, though: "All positional parameters must precede keyword parameters." Were you able to get the desired output without this error message?

Comment: `newweek` needs an `=` - fixing in the answer via edit.

Comment: Also, the percent need to be less than 1.  Thank you so much, Joe.  This is awesome....elegant and functional.  Kudos.